# How can i call parent promise from child promise?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I've a function like this:

```
function promiseCall() {

  //Parent Promise
  ParentPromise({
    ...code here...
  }).then(function() {


    //Child Promise
        ChildPromise({
          ..code here...
        }).then(function(response) {
         var result = response.result;
           if(result){
             // I want to call again Parent Promise from here
           }
        });

});

};
```

I call promiseCall function then execute Parent Promise then execute child promise. After executing child promise based on a condition i want to call again Parent promise. How is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it recursively:

```js
function promiseCall(arg) {
    return ParentPromise(...).then(function() {
        return ChildPromise(...);
    }).then(function(response) {
        var result = response.result.items;
        var newArg = ... ;
        var finalReturn = '...';
        return result ? promiseCall(newArg) :  finalReturn;
    }); 
}

var arg = ...;
promiseCall(arg).then(function(res) {
    console.log('finalReturn: ', res);
});
```